# Need to insert a record if count = 0 else update the record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to write a query where i need to check the count record if count is 0, I am suppose to insert a record else update the record

If I do the same thing using cursor, it works fine but the same thing doesnt work with no cursor

Here is my query (with no cursor)

---Without cursor

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].Products_Del  (product_Id, product_Del_startdate)                 
        SELECT f.product_Id, min(cast(product_startdate as datetime)) AS    orig_order_date FROM   [dbo].Products f
            inner  join [dbo].Products_Del ac on f.product_Id = ac.product_Id
            WHERE  Product_Status = 'ORDERED'
            AND    product_startdate != '.'    
            AND (select COUNT(*) FROM  products f1  
            INNER JOIN dbo.Products_Del ac on f1.product_Id = ac.product_Id 
            where f1.product_Id = f.product_Id) = 0  
            GROUP BY f.product_Id --order by product_Id



-- Update if exists
        ;with cts 
        AS ( 
            SELECT  product_Id , min(cast(product_startdate as datetime)) as orig_date from [dbo].Products f
                WHERE product_Id in (select product_Id from Products_Del)
                and  Product_Status = 'ORDERED'
                AND    product_startdate != '.'    -- ignore rows where date is unknown
                AND (select COUNT(*) FROM  Products f1  
                INNER JOIN dbo.Products_Del ac on f1.Product_id = ac.Product_id 
                where f1.product_Id = f.product_Id) = 1  
                GROUP BY product_Id 
            )
        UPDATE ac
        SET ac.product_Del_startdate = cts.orig_date
        FROM Products_Del ac
        INNER JOIN cts ON ac.product_Id = cts.product_Id
```

But this works good (with cursor)

```
DECLARE @v_count        INT
    DECLARE @c_product_id   INT
    DECLARE @c_product_date DATETIME


DECLARE  cursor1 CURSOR FOR
SELECT product_id,
       min(cast(product_startdate as DATETIME)) AS orig_order_date
FROM   [dbo].Products
WHERE  Product_Status = 'ORDERED'
AND    product_startdate != '.'    -- ignore rows where date is unknown
GROUP BY product_id
--order by product_id

OPEN cursor1
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @c_product_id,@c_product_date
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @v_count = COUNT(*)
             FROM   [dbo].Products_Del
            WHERE  product_Id = @c_product_id
            IF @v_count = 1 
            BEGIN
               -- If so, plug the date into that row.
               UPDATE [dbo].Products_Del
               SET    product_Del_startdate = @c_product_date
               WHERE  product_Id = @c_product_id
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
               -- If not, then create a new row in the aircraft_delivery_status table
               IF @v_count = 0 
               BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO [dbo].Products_Del
                         (product_Id, product_Del_startdate)
                  VALUES (@c_product_id, @c_product_date)
               END 
            END 

     FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO @c_product_id,@c_product_date       

END
CLOSE cursor1
DEALLOCATE cursor1
```

SQL Fiddle link with schema
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7d0d/1

Comment: Check out the MERGE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the insert statement you have incorrect join

```
inner  join [dbo].Products_Del ac on f.product_Id = ac.product_Id
```

just remove it

In the update statement (or ctp) you have incorrect condition :

```
(select COUNT(*) FROM  Products f1  
                INNER JOIN dbo.Products_Del ac on f1.Product_id = ac.Product_id 
                where f1.product_Id = f.product_Id) =
```

1

because you have multiple rows with the same product_id in products table you can get more than one row in this subquery

Also I can suggest following query:

```
WITH OrderedProducts as(
  SELECT p.product_id as product_id, 
         min(cast(product_startdate as datetime)) as start_date
  FROM [dbo].[Products] as p
  WHERE p.Product_Status = 'ORDERED'
      AND p.Product_startdate != '.'
  GROUP BY p.product_id
)
UPDATE pd
 SET pd.product_Del_startdate = op.start_date
 FROM Products_Del pd
     INNER JOIN OrderedProducts as op ON pd.product_Id = op.product_Id 

;WITH OrderedProducts as(
  SELECT p.product_id as product_id, 
         min(cast(product_startdate as datetime)) as start_date
  FROM [dbo].[Products] as p
  WHERE p.Product_Status = 'ORDERED'
      AND p.Product_startdate != '.'
  GROUP BY p.product_id
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].Products_Del  (product_Id, product_Del_startdate)
  SELECT op.product_id, op.start_date FROM OrderedProducts as op
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT pd.product_id FROM [dbo].Products_Del as pd
      WHERE pd.product_id = op.product_id )
```